# Check for the Existence of a Possible Combination of Values in an Array which Sum to a Given Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

*FOR MODERATOR:*

The question for which this is a supposed duplicate of, does not address a number of issues.

1. This question is not about how the operators work per se, but how
   they function in the algorithm, i.e. why those operators at that point.
2. This question also includes the bit-wise comparison '&' operator, which the
   other question does not address at all.
3. The central insight to the answer provided is that by assigning
   `combinationsCount = 1 << listSize` one turns the iterator 'i'  in the loop
   into a bit vector, which can be tested against a particular 'j' to determine
   if it should be included in the sum to test.

This is a solution to a variation of the coin change problem, I think. The code works, to the best of my knowledge, but I do not understand how the last if check:

```js
if (i & (1 << j)) {
    combinationSum += arr[j];
}
```

works in this algorithm (see below). I ran into it working through a tutorial. I'd really appreciate any explanation of how that portion of the code works.

*UPDATE*:

To be clear, I understanding *WHAT* the operators are doing, i.e. the bit shifting and the bit-wise addition. What I want to know is how they operate within the algorithm.

```js
possibleCombinationSumN(arr, n) {
  if (arr.indexOf(n) >= 0) {
    return true;
  }

  if (arr[0] > n) {
    return false;
  }

  if (arr[arr.length - 1] > n) {
    arr.pop();
    return possibleCombinationSumN(arr, n);
  }

  var listSize = arr.length, combinationsCount = (1 << listSize)
  for (var i = 1; i < combinationsCount; i++) {
    var combinationSum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
      if (i & (1 << j)) {
        combinationSum += arr[j];
      }
    }
    if (n === combinationSum) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Small clarification: "bit-wise comparison '&' operator" - it is not a comparison operator, it is a bitwise "and" operator. It is very often used to extract a single bit, like it is here (as it copies bits at `1`, but zeroes the bits at `0`); in this case, it is called "masking", and the "pattern" for the extraction (`1<<j` in this case) is called a "mask". There is no explicit comparison here, and none done by `&`: the implicit comparison is by JavaScript, `if (i & (1 << j) == true)`, and it works because JS considers `0` to be a falsy value, and any other number a truthy one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and now the term bit mask becomes a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` serves as a bitvector (row of zeroes and ones) that turn on or off the participation of the corresponding array values in the sum.

For example, if `arr` has 4 elements, when `i` is `11`, its binary representation is `0b1011`; this indicates that we should sum up `arr[3] + arr[1] + arr[0]`, and leave out `arr[2]`.

Now - for a four-element array, `i` will go from `0` to `15`. Why? Because `1 << arr.length` is binary `0b10000` (`0b1` shifted left four positions), or `16`, and we loop to just under that. This gives us binary values between `0b0000` and `0b1111` - i.e. all possible combinations of four ones and zeroes. If we then sum up the corresponding array values, we will have tested all possible combinations of sums.

`i & (1 << j)` tests if the `j`-th bit is `1`.

Say `j` is `3`, and `i` the abovementioned `11` (`0b1011`). `1 << j` is `0b1000`; `0b1011 & 0b1000` is `0b1000`, which is truthy. There is a one at position `3`, and `arr[3]` gets to be in the `combinationSum`.

Say `j` is `2`. `1 << j` is `0b10`; `0b1011 & 0b100` is `0b0`, which is falsy. There is a zero at position `2`; `arr[2]` does not get summed.

Comment: While expressing thanks is discouraged on SO, thanks! This was explanation for which I was looking.